# How to stop Navigation bar from scrolling with my posts?

Tags: tumblr

blog: http://mattdomchristom.tumblr.com

As you can see, when you scroll down, the navigation bar at the top follows and it's annoying. How can I just make it stay at the top of the page?

This is my HTML:

```
<head>

<!--Default Variables-->
<!--Colors-->
<meta name="color:Background" content="#000"/>
<meta name="color:Text" content="#fff"/>
<meta name="color:Post Title" content="#1C1C1C"/>
<meta name="color:Link" content="#8B7D7B"/>
<meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#d8d8d8"/>
<meta name="color:Blog Title" content="#8b0000"/>
<meta name="color:Links Text" content="#e7e7e7"/>
<meta name="color:Links Hover" content="#fff"/>
<meta name="color:Ask Background" content="#838b8b"/>

<!--Images-->
<meta name="image:Background" content""/>
<meta name="image:Sidebar" content=""/>

<!--Options-->
<meta name="if:Infinite Scrolling" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Pagination" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Glitterati Cursor" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Tiny Scrollbar" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Box shadows" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Ask" content=""/>
<meta name="if:Archive" content=""/>

<meta name= "if:Link 1" content="link1"/>
<meta name= "if:Link 2" content="link2"/>
<meta name= "if:Link 3" content="link3"/>
<meta name= "if:Link 4" content="link4"/>


<!--Links-->
<meta name="text:Link 1 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 1 name" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 2 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 2 name" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 3 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 3 name" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 4 URL" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Link 4 name" content=""/>

{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
<title>
{block:PostSummary}
{PostSummary} - {/block:PostSummary}{Title}</title>

{block:ifinfinitescrolling}<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling/code"></script>{/block:ifinfinitescrolling}

</style>

<style type="text/css">

{block:ifGlitteraticursor}
body, a, a:hover {cursor: url(http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m10gu8MJ7Z1r869vr.gif), progress;}{/block:ifGlitteraticursor}


{block:iftinyscrollbar}
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 8px; height: 9px; background :#fff; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #000000; -webkit-border-radius: 0ex; border: 0px #D4D8DB;}
{/block:iftinyscrollbar}

body{
background-color: {color:Background};
background-image: url({image:Background});
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
letter -spacing:0px;
color:{color:Text};
text-align:justify;
}

a:link, a:active, a:visited{
color: {color:Link};
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
color: {color:Link Hover};
text-decoration:underline;
}

#container {
margin:auto;
position:right;
width:1200px;
color: {color:Title};
_margin-left:10%;
}

#content {
float:center;
width:508px;
padding: 2px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 300px;
background: clear;
}

#entry {
margin-top:15px;
padding:3px;
background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/j4dtzbm/Amxlg5cp4/transparentg.png);
{block:ifboxshadows};
box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
{/block:ifboxshadows}
{block:ifboxborders}
border: 1px solid black;
{/block:ifboxborders}
}

#entry img{
{block:IndexPage}max-width:500px;{/block:IndexPage}
}


#side {
position:fixed !important;
width: 220px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 500px ;
padding: 2px ;
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: lowercase;
background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/j4dtzbm/Amxlg5cp4/transparentg.png);
{block:ifboxshadows};
box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
{/block:ifboxshadows}
}

#side2 {
position:fixed !important;
width: 753px;
height: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
background-color:black;
opacity: .8;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: -30px ;
padding: 2px ;
}

.navigate a{
color: {color:Links Text};
display:block;
width: 85px;
height: 15px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 2px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
z-index: 999;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size: 14px;
display: inline-block;
}
.navigate a:hover{
color: {color:Links Hover};
text-decoration: none;
}

.permalink{
display: block;
padding:1px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:4px;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.blogtitle{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 22px;
color: {color:Blog Title};
}

.posttitle{
font-size: 17px;
line-height: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: {color:Post Title};
letter-spacing: 1;
font-weight: none;
}


blockquote{
padding:0px 0px 2px 5px;
margin:0px 0px 2px 1px;
border-left: 1px solid {color:Text};}
blockquote p, ul{margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

.chat .line{
margin: 0 0 0px;
padding: 2px;
}
.chat .line.odd{
}

.label {font-weight:bold; color:{color:text}}

.question {
color:{color:Text};
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height:95%;
background: {color:Ask Background};
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 10px 15px;
position: relative;
-moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

.questionarrow {
width: 13px;
height: 7px;
font-size:30px;
position: absolute;
color:{color:Ask Background};
bottom: -3.5px;
left: 260px;
}


.asker {width:500px; text-align:left; color:{color:Text};font-family: silkscreen;font-size: 9px;}
.asker a {color:{color:Text};}
.asker img {float:left; margin-left:220px; vertical-align:top; margin-right:3px; max-height:15px;}




a img{border: 0px;}

.p { padding-top: 5px; }
.ol, ul { margin-left: 10px; padding: 5px; }
.ul { list-style-type: square; }

.albumart { margin-bottom: 0px; }
.albumart img, .audio embed { width: 60px; }

.video embed, .post div.video object {width:250px !important; height:187px !important;}

.notes img{width:10px; position:left; top:3px;}

.tags {
width:auto;
solid {color:Links};
font-size: 10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:{color:link};
padding:2px;
line-height:1;
margin-left:1px;
}

.tags a:hover{
color: {color:Link Hover};
text-decoration:underline;
}

#pages {
float: center;
width: 753px;
height: 22px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
color: {color:Link};
background-color: white;
opacity: .6;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 300px ;
padding: 2px;
padding-top: 6px;
}

{font-size: 100%;}

{CustomCSS}
</style>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{Title}" href="{RSS}" />

{block:ifinfinitescrolling}<style>#toTop {display:none;text-decoration:none;position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:20px;overflow:hidden;width:30px;height:40px;border:none;text-indent:-999px;background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/hi8vwsz/Q0ull6xz3/totop.png) no-repeat left top;z-index:3000;}#toTopHover {background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/hi8vwsz/Q0ull6xz3/totop.png) no-repeat left -40px;
width:30px;height:40px;display:block;overflow:hidden;float:left;opacity: 0;-moz-opacity: 0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {outline:none;}#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {outline:none;}</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/53unaru/kx3lgzker/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/53unaru/4jtlgzkf8/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/53unaru/y8wlgzkbt/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
});
</script>{/block:ifinfinitescrolling}


</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="side2">

<div class="navigate">

<a href="/" >home</a>
{block:ifAsk}
<a href="/ask" >message</a>
{/block:ifAsk}

{block:iflink1}
<a href="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1 name}</a>
{/block:iflink1}
{block:iflink2}
<a href="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2 name}</a>
{/block:iflink2}
{block:iflink3}
<a href="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3 name}</a>
{/block:iflink3}
{block:iflink4}
<a href="{text:Link 4 URL}">{text:Link 4 name}</a>
{/block:iflink4}
<a href="/archive" >archive</a>
<a href="http://sociallyawkwardgiraffe.tumblr.com/" >Theme</a>
</div>
</div>
</center>

<div id="side">

<center>
<div class="blogtitle"><a href="/">{Title}</a></div>
</center>
<br>

<a href="/"><img src="{image:sidebar}" width=220px></a>


{Description}

</div>

</div>

</div>



<div id="content">
{block:Posts}
<div id="entry">

<center>
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="permalink" style="letter-spacing:1px;"><l><a href="{Permalink}"> {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} • {NoteCountWithLabel}</a><a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank" class="details"> • Reblog</a></l>
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
</center>

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<span class="posttitle">{Title}</span>
{/block:Title}<span class="entrytext">{Body}</span>
{/block:text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{URL}" class="posttitle">{Name}</a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
{/block:link}

{block:Photo}
{LinkOpenTag}
<a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=500px
{LinkCloseTag}
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}<center>{Photoset-500}</center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
<span class="title">{Quote}</span>
{block:Source}<i> - {Source}</i>{/block:Source}<br>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Quote}


{block:Chat}
{block:title}<div id="posttitle"><center>{Title}<br></center></div>
{/block:title}<div class="chat">
{block:Lines}<div class="chat"><div class="line {Alt}"><div class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}<span class="label"><b>{Label}</b></span>
{/block:Label}{Line}</div>
</div></div>{/block:Lines}</div>{/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}
{block:albumart}<div class="albumart"><img src="{albumarturl}" align="left"></div>
{/block:albumart}<div style="width: 310px; height: 20px;">
{AudioPlayerblack}</div><BR>{block:TrackName}<span><strong>Title</strong>:
{TrackName}</span>{/block:TrackName}<br>
{block:Artist}<span><strong>Artist:</strong>
{Artist}</span>{/block:Artist}<br>
{/block:Audio}

{block:Video}<center>{Video-500}<BR>
</center>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Video}

{block:Answer}
<div class="question">
<div class="questionarrow">▼</div>
{Question}
</div>
<div class="asker"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-24}">{Asker}</div>
<div class="answer">{Answer}</div>
{/block:answer}

{block:HasTags}<div class="tags"> tags: {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}" target="_blank">#{Tag} </a>{/block:Tags}</div>{/block:HasTags}
</center>

{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}
{/block:PostNotes}</div>{/block:Posts}

</center>
</div>
<div id="pages">
{block:ifpagination}
<center>
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}" title="newer">&larr;</a>{/block:PreviousPage} {CurrentPage} of {TotalPages} {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}" title="older">&rarr;</a>
{/block:NextPage}

{/block:ifpagination}
<center>
</center>
</div>

</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Custom CSS box in your customization screen, enter the following:

```
#side2 {
  position: relative!important;
}
```